# How do I access finger location/movement information in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell, swipe

So what I'm trying to do is have each cell in my tableview have the ability to be swiped left or right. If I can grab the finger location/translation I could change the content's x anchors and bingo bango, but I'm having a real hard time figuring it out. if anyone can help, it would be so so rad

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you fail?

Comment: so far ive failed figuring out how to access the tableview's pangesture, but adding another pangesture makes the tablesview's unusable

Comment: There is third party library available like https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

Answer (score 0):

You can check the apple documentation about **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** , The default direction is right, also explore this function **UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection** it return you the direction is in right, left, top , or bottom . Here is demonstration

```
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

var swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


    switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            print("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            print("Swiped down")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            print("Swiped left")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
            print("Swiped up")
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thank you but swipegesture has a binary output right? i want the cell to follow the user's finger and once it passes a threshhold it animates to the left or right depending on which direction